# Ошибка "Несовместимые типы" при уничтожении динамического массива, переданного в процедуру

Tags: delphi

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;

procedure proc(arr: array of integer);
begin
  arr:=nil;                       //incompatible types: 'Poiter' and 'Array of integer
  setlength(arr, 28);             //incompatible types
end;

var arr: array of integer;
begin

setlength(arr, 21);  
arr[9]:=67;
proc(arr);

readln;
end.
```

Что делать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi не очень любит формулировки `array of ...` в сигнатурах процедур и функций.

Определите явный тип для массива и все получится.

```
type
  TIntArray = array of integer;

procedure proc(arr: TIntArray);
begin
  writeln(arr[9]);
  setlength(arr, 28);
end;

var arr: TIntArray;
begin
  setlength(arr, 21);
  arr[9]:=67;
  proc(arr);
  readln;
end.
```